# Удалить комбинации символов из строки

Tags: c++

помогите сделать задание: даны 2 символа С и R и строка S. Удалить все сочетания этих символов (СС, RR, RС, СR) из строки S.

```
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char s1[200];
    char s2[2];
    char s4[2];
    char s3[] = {""};
    cout << "Введіть рядок" << endl;
    gets_s(s1);
    cout << "Введіть 1 символ який бажаєте видалити" << endl;
    gets_s(s2);
    cout << "Введіть 2 символ який бажаєте видалити" << endl;
    gets_s(s4);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1-1); i++)
    {
        if (s1[i]==s2[0]&&s1[i+1]==s2[0] s1[i] == s4[0] && s1[i + 1] == s4[0]  s1[i] == s2[0] && s1[i + 1] == s4[0] || s1[i] == s4[0] && s1[i + 1] == s2[0])
        {
             s1[i]=' ';
             s1[i + 1]=' ';
        }
    }
     cout << s1;
}
```

Comment: А в чем конкретная проблема вашего кода? `s1[i] == s2[0] && s1[i + 1] == s2[0] s1[i] == s4[0] && s1[i + 1] == s4[0]  s1[i] == s2[0] && s1[i + 1] == s4[0] || s1[i] == s4[0] && s1[i + 1] == s2[0]` что это за строчка? И почему она вообще должна работать?

Comment: Удалить — это заменить на пробелы (у вас так)? И как быть с, например, ССС — оставлять одну С или убирать все три?

Comment: Нужна убрать все такие комбинации со строчки